# Migrating or representing a Microsoft SQL Database on the Chain

Tags: ipfs, hyperledger-fabric, mysql

I am wondering what is the best way to migrate or represent a massive, 50 table, Medical Health Records SQL Database on the Blockchain.  Is it best done with IPFS hash on Ethereum or is Hyperledger a better solution?

Comment: What is the size of DB ? (Number of records, size of data in GB? )

Comment: tens of gigs of data @ShamitVerma

Comment: I think I can do this with IPFS and Ethereum; my only concern is incentivizing nodes to seed the encrypted medical records.. @ShamitVerma

Comment: Do you plan to use public Ethereum chain or a private chain ?

Comment: Probably private to avoid transaction costs for the migration @ShamitVerma

Comment: In that case; you can use "proof of authority". Nodes do not need any incentive to mine and they keep mining at pre-defined rate. It is fairly straight-forward to create a test network and validate.